# Maximize function of eigenvalues related to a quadratic Lyapunov function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, linear-control

I would like to solve the following problem

$$
\begin{align}
\max_Q\ & \frac{\lambda_\text{min}(Q)}{2\,\lambda_\text{max}(P)} \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_\text{min}(P)}{\lambda_\text{max}(P)}} \\
s.t.\ & P\,A + A^\top P = -Q \\
& Q = Q^\top \succ 0
\end{align}
$$

where $A$ is a (real) Hurwitz matrix and $\lambda_\text{min/max}(X)$ denote the smallest/largest eigenvalue of $X$ respectively. There will always be infinitely many solutions, since if $\mathcal{Q}$ is a solution then $\alpha\,\mathcal{Q}$ with $\alpha > 0$ will be a solution as well. This can be shown using $\lambda_\text{min/max}(\alpha\,X) = \alpha\,\lambda_\text{min/max}(X)$ and the fact that if $\mathcal{P}$ is the solution of the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) corresponding to $\mathcal{Q}$, then $\alpha\,\mathcal{P}$ is the solution corresponding to $\alpha\,\mathcal{Q}$ (since multiplying matrices by a scalar commutes). Therefore, one can limit the solution by adding the constraint that $\lambda_\text{min}(Q) = 1$. This also removes the need of the constraint that $Q$ has to be positive definite, since $\lambda_\text{min}(Q) = 1$ already ensures that all the other eigenvalues are also positive. Therefore, that constraint can be reduced to just $Q = Q^\top$.

When excluding the square root term from the cost function it can be shown that the optimal $Q$ would be the identity matrix. For that one can use the integral definition of the $P$ matrix

$$
P(Q) - P(I) = \int_0^\infty e^{A^\top t} \underbrace{\left(Q - I\right)}_{\geq 0} e^{A\,t}\,dt \geq 0
$$

so $\lambda_\text{max}(P(Q)) \geq \lambda_\text{max}(P(I))$ and therefore $\lambda_\text{max}(P(Q))^{-1} \leq \lambda_\text{max}(P(I))^{-1}$.

But when I include the square root term then this does not seem to be the case any more. For example when using

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and limiting $Q$ to a pure diagonal form, ordered from smallest to largest, then the cost function as a function of $\lambda_\text{max}(Q)$ can be seen in the figure below. If I solve it using a nonlinear solver I get a maximum of 0.1518, which is even higher then the maximum in the figure. So the general solution also does not even seem to be of a diagonal form.

[image]

One could always use numerical methods. But this would probably require estimating the gradient, since especially for larger $A$ there is not a closed form solution for the eigenvalues and therefore also not for their partial derivatives. So the converges rate might not be great. I am also not sure if this problem would even be [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) (only one maximum). So are there any insights that could be used to help solving this problem?

---

For the people who would like to know the context; I am looking at nonvanishing perturbations using Lemma 9.2 from the book Nonliear Systems 3rd edition, by Hassan K. Khalil.

Comment: Are u optimizing the cost-function only in $Q$? or $Q$ and $P$?

Comment: @induction601 By choosing a $Q$ there is always a given solution for $P$, so I need to find the $Q$ that maximizes the function.

Comment: I see. $P$ depends on $Q$. $P(Q)$. Interesting problem.

Comment: I think you need to use a diagonal matrix with different entries. Otherwise it will return a conservative answer.  The square root term is the spread of eigs of P which should be minimized. There should be a better way to formulate this cost function though it's been years since I've touched that book.